# Is 1 Session Token enough for multiple Ajax Request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, csrf

I have a security question today. I'm implementing Ajax to my application with the use of jQuery. I'm actually generating a Token on each page load which will be set as a `$_SESSION` and it is being sent to the `$.ajax()` request. On the server side I'm verifying if the sent `$_POST` token equals to the `$_SESSION` one.

Here is the html part:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.min.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        "use strict";

        <?php            
            $token = md5(rand(5000,500000));
            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        ?>


        SomeFunction.init("<?php echo $token; ?>");
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

So this will basically SET the $token eac htime a page loads. But what if my page does have Multiple Ajax requests? Or just one, it doesn't matter. If the current user knows the Token (by viewing the source code), than he can send malformed requests with it, if he doesn't reload the page in the meantime.

So basically he will have the token for as long as he wants and he can send as many malformed Ajax requests as he wants.

How is it possible defend against these kind of attacks? Should I regenerate the Token on each Ajax request? How is that actually possible without reloading the page? Should  return a new token value with each Ajax request? Or what are the best practices for this?

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding CSRF.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: Sorry I've mistyped the title. I'm just looking to secure my ajax requests with tokens.

Comment: You cannot trust data from the client, period.  There is no way to tell the difference between your own request and a malicious one.

Comment: So why are these Tokens implemented into applicaitons? Only to prevent CSRF? No other meaning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make multiple AJAX request using the same session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624370/make-multiple-ajax-request-using-the-same-session)